# Meteor templates. How can I not render a HTML element based on an {{#if}}?

Tags: mongodb, if-statement, meteor, spacebars

I have a collection that stores phone numbers for companies.
If a company has a phone number, draw those phone numbers.
If a company has no phone number, don't draw any.

Currently it half works.  It will not draw the phone numbers if no numbers are in the collection, but it still draws the < h4 >Phone< /h4 > heading and I don't want it to.

Here's the code:

```
<template name="orgPage">
    <h2>Organisation Name: {{name}}</h2>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>
        {{#if phone}}
            <h4>Phone</h4>
            {{#each phone}}
                <li>{{number}} ({{type}})</li>
            {{/each}}
        {{else}}
            <p>No contact numbers</p>
        {{/if}}  
    </ul>
</template>
```

and

```
Template.orgPage.helpers({

    'phone': function() {
        return organisationsPhoneNumbers.find({ orgId: currentOrgId })
    }

});
```

How can I get it to NOT draw the < h4 >Phone< /h4 > if there is no data returned from the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**short answer**

Keep all of your original code and replace `{{#if phone}}` with `{{#if phone.count}}`

**long answer**

Spacebars has a really cool [path evaluation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spacebars#path-evaluation) feature, which is best explained with an example.

Imagine you have a `post` document in your current context. Each `post` is [modeled](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/models) to have a `fetchAuthor` helper, which returns a user document. Let's suppose you need the lower cased version of the author's last name. In JavaScript you could write something like:

```
post.fetchAuthor().profile.firstName.toLowerCase()
```

Now if we need that value in a template we can write:

```
{{post.fetchAuthor.profile.firstName.toLowerCase}}
```

As spacebars evaluates each identifier in the path, it checks to see if it's a function - if it is, it invokes it. Note this only works if the called functions take no arguments.

Circling back to our original example, the `phone` helper returns a cursor, which has a `count` function. We can write `{{#if phone.count}}` and spacebars will figure out that we mean `phone.count()` because `count` is a function.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea. I never ran across that in the docs! Time for some code cleanup!

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame this isn't more well known. I find it's a great way to reduce the number of helpers needed to render a template.

Comment: Updated all my code to use this pattern, thanks David!

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem early on, here's a simple approach where you return an object from the helper that includes the count:

**js:**

```
Template.orgPage.helpers({
  'phone': function() {
    var cursor = organisationsPhoneNumbers.find({ orgId: currentOrgId });
    return { count: cursor.count(), items: cursor };
  }
})
```

**html:**

```
 {{#if phone.count}}
   <h4>Phone</h4>
   {{#each phone.items}}
     <li>{{number}} ({{type}})</li>
   {{/each}}
 {{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks you @Michel Floyd, very concise and simple.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @robster - you should mark David Weldon's answer as the correct one, it's even more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly standard pattern for this kind of scenarios that avoids re-running the same helper multiple times:

```handlebars
<template name="orgPage">
    <h2>Organisation Name: {{name}}</h2>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    {{#with phone}}
      {{#if count}}
        <h4>Phone</h4>
        <ul>
          {{#each .}}
            <li>{{number}} ({{type}})</li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      {{else}}
        <p>No contact numbers</p>
      {{/if}}  
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

The `with` block sets the scope for its content to the result of the`phone` helper, which is a cursor.

It then checks `if` the `count()` helper/method is truth-y. If so, it uses an `each` iterator tor render the list of items, `else` - the message indicating no numbers is displayed.

Note that there is an `each...else` clause that works if you don't need anything outside the `each` block.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you.  I'm giving the solution to @Michel Floyd though for the simplicity of the Template that results from his code.  This was exactly correct also though.  Thanks again, with great answers like yours I'm learning all the time.  Rob

Comment: Feel free to pick any solution that works for you. I try to keep efficiency in mind and eliminate unnecessary cursor fetches. That's why I'm using `#with` (otherwise you have 2 different where the internal one depends on the external). The other changes I made were to remove the `h4` from the list and use the `count()` helper (as David points out in his answer).